# mongoose: dont update if value is "" but do update otherwise

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When updating one record if the value is "" the existing value gets overwritten and I dont want it to be...

```
      const company = "myCo"
      const name = "someName"
      const description = '';
      const image = ''
      const updated = await assetClasses
        .updateOne(
          { company, name },
          {
            $set: {
              description,
              image,
            },
          }, 
          {
            upsert: true,
          }
        )
        .exec();
```

The data looks like

```
_id:5e38002a56fa5e54f1fe10de
indistructable:false
company:"myCo"
description:"dont overwrite me"
image:"myimage.png"
name:"someName"
supply:10000
createdAt:2020-02-03T11:12:42.371+00:00
updatedAt:2020-02-03T13:21:35.924+00:00
__v:0
```

Answer (score 1):

I've developed some variants assuming that you only want to avoid empty strings, so this is all about strings.

**Variant 1** (accepting not empty string; if empty - get the existing value from db):

```
const setIfNotEmptyString = (value, defaultValue) => ({
  $switch: {
    branches: [{
      case: {
        $not: {
          $eq: [value, '']
        }
      },
      then: value
    }],
    default: defaultValue
  }
});

await assetClasses.updateOne({
  company, name
}, [{
  $set: {
    description: setIfNotEmptyString(description, "$description"),
    image: setIfNotEmptyString(image, "$image")
  }
}], { upsert: true }).exec();
```

**Variant 2** (same as 1, more simple):

```
const setIfNotEmptyString = (value, defaultValue) => ({ $cond: [{ $not: {$eq: [value, '']} }, value, defaultValue] });

await assetClasses.updateOne({
  company, name
}, [{
  $set: {
    description: setIfNotEmptyString(description, "$description"),
    image: setIfNotEmptyString(image, "$image")
  }
}], { upsert: true }).exec();
```

**Variant 3** (editing model, do not allow to store empty strings):
For example if your mongoose model looks like:

```
{
    ...
    description: String,
    image: String
}
```

Then you can just simply add extra rules:

```
{   ...
    description: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 1
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 1
    }
}
```

And in your update queries you need to pass option `runValidators`

> { runValidators: true }

You can combine variants 1/2 with 3 as well.

Source:

1. [MongoDB use of $set operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#update-method-agg-pipeline) + [examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#update-method-examples)
2. [Mongoose validators (minLength)](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#built-in-validators) + [runValidators option](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators)